# I need help putting two select query's into one stored procedure for one output?

Tags: mysql

I tried a union and union all but I get an error incorrect usage of union.

```
select  sr.shipper_city,
        sr.consignee_site_city,
        cast((avg(round((to_seconds(sr.delv_live_start)- to_seconds(sr.pick_depart_loaded))/(60*60*24),1))) as decimal)  as TransitDays90
from cs.shipment_reporting sr
where customer_id = '15619' 
and (pick_depart_loaded >(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
group by sr.shipper_city,sr.consignee_site_city
order by sr.shipper_city,sr.consignee_site_city


select sr.shipper_city,
       sr.consignee_site_city,
      (cast((avg(round((to_seconds(sr.delv_live_start)- to_seconds(sr.pick_depart_loaded))/(60*60*24),1))) as decimal))  as TransitDays30
from cs.shipment_reporting sr
where sr.customer_id = '15619' and (sr.pick_depart_loaded >(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
group by sr.shipper_city,sr.consignee_site_city
order by sr.shipper_city,sr.consignee_site_city
```

Comment: "I tried a union and union all"  what error ? How did you try?   Why did you not try it as is explained here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html ?

Comment: HINT: Only 1 `ORDER BY`  is allowed in a query, because SQL cannot order the first part in a different way than the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the order by in outer query, try:

```
select shipper_city,consignee_site_city,TransitDays90
from (
         select  sr.shipper_city,
                 sr.consignee_site_city,
                 cast((avg(round((to_seconds(sr.delv_live_start)- to_seconds(sr.pick_depart_loaded))/(60*60*24),1))) as decimal)  as TransitDays90
         from cs.shipment_reporting sr
         where customer_id = '15619' 
         and (pick_depart_loaded >(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
         group by sr.shipper_city,sr.consignee_site_city
                                 ---- removed order by , it has no effect
         UNION
         
         select  sr.shipper_city,
                 sr.consignee_site_city,
                 (cast((avg(round((to_seconds(sr.delv_live_start)- to_seconds(sr.pick_depart_loaded))/(60*60*24),1))) as decimal))  as TransitDays30
         from cs.shipment_reporting sr
         where sr.customer_id = '15619' and (sr.pick_depart_loaded >(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
         group by sr.shipper_city,sr.consignee_site_city

      ) as t1 
order by shipper_city , consignee_site_city ;
```

Comment: Your code was awesome in that i got the appropriate answers but is there anyway to distinguish the ones that are 30 days vs 90 days?  I added a field Months and set it to 30 for one and 90 for the other but when i ran it together it didn't pull in the new field.  Seperately, it does do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Never mind found it and THANK you  so much for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries have different column names: TransitDays90 and TransitDays30.

Based on your demands, you can either change them to the same or add NULL columns to each query, but make sure that order and number of columns is same in each query

Comment: yes the field can be same name.  The value needs to be either 30 or 90.  Field name can be transit